# Test Excel cell value against SQL Server field

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I have an Excel form that contains a project name that I want to make sure is unique when compared to values in a SQL table.  I want to do this without importing the SQL table into the worksheet. I was thinking of something like this:

```vb
Dim uniqueProjectName as Int
Dim suggstedProjectName as String

suggestedProjectName = WorkSheets("Form").Range("ProjectName")

If (Select Count(pName) from PROJECTS.dbo.Projects WHERE pName = suggestedProjectName)  = 0
Then uniqueProjectName = 1 
Else uniqueProjectName = 0
```

Can anyone help with the syntax?

Comment: https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm

Comment: Your `If` block is illegal syntax. `Then` should be on the same line as `If`, `Else` should be on its own line, and there needs to be an `End If` to close the conditional block. Also Excel won't magically evaluate a T-SQL string without a database connection, and you probably want `COUNT(*)` - TSQL syntax looks ok otherwise.

Comment: Lookup everything about using ADODB in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I was able to use an ADODB connection and everything works as designed now....